# How to link HTML page with python

Tags: python, html

I have a form in an HTML page that reads input from a user (string x), and I have my python script that uses this variable.

What is the easiest way to fetch this variable from the HTML page by the python script (.py) and return the result - which should also be a string -  to show it in the HTML page again?

Answer (score 1):

You can use either a modern WSGI environment like [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) or [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/), or if the utility is very small, you can take a look at [Common Gateway Interface (CGI)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/cgi.html).

Comment: Thanks, CGI is what I'm looking for, I try to use Django before but a lot of time needed to fix installation issues while I need it for a small utility.